# Should I use bin/rake db:migrate or bin/rails db:migrate?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, command-line-interface, ruby-on-rails-5

> Why are some commands living in bin/rails and some commands living in bin/rake?

Comment: I would love to understand why someone downvoted this question. Its relevancy is made clear by the very fact that the changelog/official documentation included this topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR `bin/rails db:migrate` from Rails 5 on should work just fine.

According to the [Official Rails 5 Beta 1 story](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2015/12/18/Rails-5-0-beta1/) this is a very common question and things are about to change:

> That’s a common question, especially for beginners, and we never had a good answer (just lots of technical excuses). So now we’ve committed to making bin/rails the one master command to rule them all. All your rake commands are available through here as a gateway, but we’ll eventually port many of them over. So your fingers will now have to get used to bin/rails db:migrate instead of bin/rake db:migrate. That should only take a few months!